# Making more windows with backgrounds (using the paths) in a for loop

Tags: python, image, for-loop, tkinter, window

I'm new to python and I'm trying this code:

```
import random
from random import choice
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import sys
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import filedialog
import os

num_npcs = 2
num_img_tot = 100
npc_window = {}
canvas = {}
background_label = {}

for i in range(0, num_npcs,1):
    num_img = round(random.uniform(0.5, num_img_tot+0.5))
    npc_window["npc_window{0}".format(i)] = Tk()
    canvas["canvas{0}".format(i)] = Canvas(npc_window["npc_window{0}".format(i)], bg="blue", height=250, width=300)
    filename["canvas{0}".format(i)] = PhotoImage(file=base_folder + 'biome\\'+str(char)+'\\'+str(int) + '\\'+str(num_img)+'.png')
    background_label["background_label{0}".format(i)] = Label(npc_window["npc_window{0}".format(i)], image=filename["canvas{0}".format(i)])
    background_label["background_label{0}".format(i)].place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
    canvas["canvas{0}".format(i)].pack()
```

but I probably messed up a little bit... I'm not used to GUI and stuff and I'm actually experimenting.
By the way the error is:

```
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist
```

I'm trying to make a program that opens X (random) images, that's why I tried Tk().
Also I'm using Pycharm in a Windows 10 machine.

Comment: please add a minimal example including imports

Comment: At least part of the problem is that you're creating more than one instance of `Tk`. You should only ever create one. If you need more windows you should be using `Toplevel`. See [Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48045401/7432)

Comment: On top of the multiple TK instance issue: The "pyimage2" error does not occur when removing the `PhotoImage` line. are you sure that your image is located in the provided position?

Comment: As far as i can tell, i provided the path in the PhotoImage function under the argument file= . 
i had some problems with the path cos of the slashes and i fixed it with :

base_folder = os.path.join(__file__).replace("/","\\").replace("encounter.py","")

replacing the actual /, from .join, with \ and removing "encounter.py" (cos i think it was __file__ to adding it)

Comment: what is the intended path? what is `str(char)` supposed to do?

Comment: \biome\alignment\1

Where alignment and 1 are variables, char is already a str so its a useless casting..

Comment: I am not sure about your operating system but at least in Linux replacing the backslash with a double backslash is not necessary

Comment: i tried with / and with \ but always:
"image "pyimage2" doesn't exist"

i wonder if its some problem with the PhotoImage, it should give me an image object from the path right?

Comment: I need the random cos i want to pick up random images from a specified path.

Comment: For your case, add `master=npc_window["npc_window{0}".format(i)]` in `PhotoImage(...)`.  However, multiple instances of `Tk()` should be avoided.

Comment: if Tk() should be avoided, how can i put images on top(in precise order) of the background without messing with the background itself?

Comment: I think you could create `Tk()` on top and then maybe create `Toplevel()` inside loops instead

Comment: I have found the problem, i think that the garbage collector may have deleted the images, i have fixed with a reference to the images themselves using the method .image:

background_label["background_label{0}".format(i)].image = filename["filename{0}".format(i)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pyimage2` error may be due to an incorrect file path. Suggestion to improve folfer path:

```
base_folder = "base_folder"
alignment_list = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
integer_list = [1,2,3]
images = []

tk = Tk()
for alignment, integer in zip(alignment_list, integer_list):
    image_name = "img" + str(integer) + ".png"
    file_name = os.path.join(base_folder, "biome", str(alignment), str(integer), image_name)
    print(file_name)
    img = PhotoImage(file=file_name)
    images.append(img)
```

Which gives

```
base_folder/biome/0.1/1/img1.png
base_folder/biome/0.2/2/img2.png
base_folder/biome/0.3/3/img3.png
```

Comment: dont forget `tk.mainloop()`

Comment: A better way to create folder paths would be to either use os.path.join or pathlib. I'm not a fan of concatenating / character together as it isn't platform independent.